# Duplicate hot question

Tags: bug, hot-questions

The [same question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/114544/20260) shows up twice at the top of the [hot questions list](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot). Hovering over the first instance says it has 154.451 hotness points, the second one says 122.4 hotness points (these numbers change frequently, so YMMV). How can the same question show up twice with different hotness points?

[image]

Comment: This is purely a guess, but it might have something to do with the question being [closed and reopened](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/114544/revisions).

Comment: I get 197 pts and then 156 pts for the two questions, but still a duplicate for me.

Comment: @Riker The numbers are obviously dynamic, due to whatever criteria is used for hotness. They've also changed for me, but it's still duped.

Comment: Where can I see this list? And what should I hover to see hotness points?

Comment: Click on **Hot Network Questions** in the sidebar, and hover over the question title.

Comment: @Qwertiy go http://stackexchange.com and hover over the two links.

Comment: @Riker, thanks. Yep, see it. And it's still duplicated :)

Comment: @DJMcMayhem yup, my guess as well. When closed, the question is excluded from the list, so maybe somehow it borked.

Comment: These are generated from a table that contains some basic information on all posts, network-wide (synced periodically from each site). For some reason, there are two entries in that table for this question... (quite possibly related to an issue that has consumed Marc & Nick's attention ATM, so give it a bit)

Comment: In anticipation of yet more votes from meta effect, please note the site advice to [stop upvoting trivial solutions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10132/20260).

Comment: I guess that question was... *two hot*.  Don't bother, you can't shame me more than I feel right now.

Comment: @Won't Sigh, we can't downvote comments.

Comment: [There are more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZVxj.png)

Comment: Appears to be fixed now.

Comment: Indeed it does. The codegolf.SE question is closed, so it's not on the list at all. The biology.SE question is still on the list, but only one time.

Comment: _@Barmar_ @Won't does that (at) Will ;-)